# lodash's mapValues for all keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash in the most elegant way possible to convert the following object:

```
var original = {
  email: {
    0: 'user01@gmail.com',
    1: 'user02@gmail.com',
    2: 'user03@gmail.com'
  },
  name: {
    0: 'Sam',
    1: 'Jack',
    2: 'Lucy'
  },
  last_name: {
    0: 'Smith',
    1: 'Green',
    2: 'Tompson'
  }
};
```

Into this:

```
var expected = [
  {
    email: 'user01@gmail.com',
    name: 'Sam',
    last_name: 'Smith'
  },
  {
    email: 'user02@gmail.com',
    name: 'Jack',
    last_name: 'Green'
  },
  {
    email: 'user03@gmail.com',
    name: 'Lucy',
    last_name: 'Tompson'
  }
];
```

I know I can use `_.mapValues(original, index);` where `index` is either `0`, `1` or `2`, but I need an array with all mapValues.

The keys in `original` are variable (sometimes there are 3, sometimes there are 2, sometimes 6) as are the number of indexes. I've found a few solutions, but they all seem too convoluted. I have a feeling there's an elegant way of doing this with a few lodash's methods. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
// _.size(_.values(original)[0]) - amount of rows (3 in that case)
var expected = _.times(_.size(_.values(original)[0]), function (index) {
    return _.mapValues(original, index);
});
```

**Edit**: one line

```
var expected = _.times(_.size(_.values(original)[0]), _.mapValues.bind(_, original));
```

Comment: I like it! Way shorter than what I had. I was trying a solution that revolved around a single chained line, but this feels cleaner.

Comment: Look at eddited answer.